# Replacing pattern in Column names of R-Tibble

Tags: r, rename

I am trying to update 23 column names in a tibble in an RMD document that all follow the same pattern (1999-05, 2000-05, etc). I am trying to remove the "-05" so it just says the year. When I have attempted to use `gsub("-05"), "")`, it tells me I'm missing an argument. When I add anything as the third argument, it turns my tibble into a set of values instead.

I have also attempted  `<- str_remove_all('-05', '')` and it returns that the pattern is not supported.

Any suggestions??

Comment: Usually renaming cols of a tiibble named `x` would be done something like this `names(x) <- gsub("-.*$","",names(x))`.

Comment: Thank you so much! This did it. I was missing the names piece of the code.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you are using dplyr already: with dplyr you can use `rename_all` to remove the same string from all columns, or `rename_at` to rename a subset of columns (in below code it is any columns containing 2000).

```
library(dplyr)

df <- tibble(`1999-05` = NA, `2000-05` = NA, `2001-05` = NA)

df %>%
    rename_all(function(x) gsub("-05$", "", x))

df %>%
    rename_at(vars(contains("2000")), function(x) gsub("-05$", "", x))
```